# How to view different polylines at different zoom levels in Flutter GoogleMaps

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, zooming, polyline

I currently have multiple polylines drawn as grids on GoogleMaps. The amount of polylines is starting to slow down my app, so I am trying to get it where only certain polylines show at certain zoom levels. Is there any way to utilize the `onCameraMove:` parameter or any other methods for achieving this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you been able to figure it out? I face the same problem so pls share your solution if you have found one.

Comment: You could use the `controller.getScreenCoordinate` method as a starting point to some calculation to get the right zoom level. Not done so yet, but i'll be happy to return to this question when i figure it out.